# Diffing two texts in Rails and printing human readable HTML output

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, diff

I'm using the paper_trail gem to auto-create a versions history of my `Page` model.

In `pages#show`, I display the versions like so:

[image: screenshot]

The most important element is the diff which shows the difference between the previous and the currently displayed version of a field, e.g. `content`. It looks like a diff on GitHub, and it is marked up well using `<ins>` for insertions and `<del>` for deletions.

The sad thing is that at the time being, I generate this diff using https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/, a JavaScript library that's run in the browser of the user. I've done it this way because I didn't manage to find a Ruby gem or similar that does the same in a similar elegant way.

Well, I found https://github.com/samg/diffy and https://github.com/pvande/differ, but the diff of both gems aren't close as elegant: differ needs to know manually whether to diff by line, word, or character (while the used JavaScript decides this automatically and uses a combination of these options which feels very intuitive to me), and diffy doesn't offer an option for this. I don't know exactly how the JavaScript works, but it states that "Myer's diff algorithm" is used internally:

> This library implements Myer's diff algorithm which is generally considered to be the best general-purpose diff. A layer of pre-diff speedups and post-diff cleanups surround the diff algorithm, improving both performance and output quality.

You can try it here: https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Maybe use the following two strings to see a typical example of two versions of a page:

```
This is the about page.

Put markdowwn formated content here.
```

and

```
This is the about page.

Put markdown formatted here content.

A [link to page 11](11). And another one: [](11).
```

It results in something like this:

[image: screenshot]

The problem with this approach is that it's run in the browser, so I can't mutate the generated code in my Rails application anymore. So I wonder whether there's an easy way to get similar diff results using e.g. a command line tool like `diff`? Maybe even `git` could be of use?